# using static libcurl.a in C program by minGW64

Tags: c, windows, curl, mingw, static-libraries

*(I saw answers of every single StOF questions regarding this - none fully helped. I'm very frustrated after trying so hard for 3 days & nights.)*

- [libcurl.a](https://curl.se/windows/) is statically linked with:

  - OpenSSL 1.1.1k [64bit/32bit]
  - brotli 1.0.9 [64bit/32bit]
  - libgsasl 1.10.0 [64bit/32bit]
  - libidn2 2.3.1 [64bit/32bit]
  - libssh2 1.9.0 [64bit/32bit]
  - nghttp2 1.43.0 [64bit/32bit]
  - zlib 1.2.11 [64bit/32bit]
  - zstd 1.5.0 [64bit/32bit]

> **Case 1** - as if curl isn't statically linked

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-10.2.0.exe  -o main.exe   main.c  "C:\curl-7.77.0-win64-mingw\lib\libcurl.a"  -DCURL_STATICLIB`

Throws unending lines of error, *as if libcurl isn't statically linked with its dependencies**:

```
...\lib\libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `nghttp2_version'
...\lib\libcurl.a(http2.o):(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `nghttp2_submit_rst_stream' 

... (then the errors include many more undefined reference to symbols from nghttp2, ssl, crypt, ssh, gsasl)
```

Comment: I'll mention the other cases I have with relevance.

Comment: A static library isn't actually linked in itself, it's really nothing more than an archive of object files. And as such linking with a static library is like linking with the actual object files themselves. If a static library have other library dependencies, you must explicitly link with those as well.

Comment: *"libcurl.a is statically linked with..."* doesn't make much sense. `libcurl.dll` can be linked with them, but not `libcurl.a`. When you link static libraries, you have to manually link their dependencies.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  curl.se/windows says: "curl 7.77.0_2 was built and statically linked with: [the list of libraries here]".

Comment: That's the curl *application*, the stand-alone program, not the library.

Comment: Do I *manually* link the *library dependencies* (the list I provided in description) of `libcurl.a` (after I static-compile every single of them) like this: `gcc.exe   -DCURL_STATICLIB   main.c   ./libcurl.a ./libnghttp2.a ./libssl.a ./libidn2  ./lib...       ` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or consider using pkg-config, which can generate those flags automatically (the easiest way would be to install it from MSYS2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It is so enormously saddening to see how many people have struggled and are still struggling to statically link `libcurl` to their program. So much so that [a very active Curl maintainer](http://github.com/bagder) said: "building static is a roller coaster left for the users to deal with on their own as its such a never-ending race for us to try to support."*

---

Since `linker` is saying *undefined references*, then `libcurl.a` must be:

- **not statically linked**
- Or, you've got the sequence of libraries unarranged. `Linker` is sensitive to sequence. Example: If `libbrotlidec-static.a` needs a function/symbol which is inside `libbrotlienc-static.a`, then `libbrotlienc-static.a` must be mentioned before `libbrotlidec-static.a`

> A static library is an archive `.a` of object `.obj` files. And they're not statically linked in themselves. That's why, to link `some-static-library.a` to a program, you need to collect and manually mention `every.a` `single.a` `static.a` `library.a` that are dependencies of `some-static-library.a`.

In my [Chat@Terminal:~$](https://github.com/midnqp/terminal.chat) project, I should have a `make.bat` file which shows how to statically link `libcurl` to a program using `gcc` or `mingw`. And finally static-compile the whole program, and ship without any runtime dependency!

---

On a side-note, [curl's precompiled-binary website](http://curl.se/windows/) says: *Curl_x.x.x is statically linked with: [list of libraries you provided]*. Break your misconception that, the statement made at the website means: `Curl.exe` is statically linked with the libs, not `libcurl`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use libcurl is to get the necessary flags via pkg-config. In MSYS2 this works quite well. Otherwise you may need to point the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the location of `libcurl.pc`.

On my system

```sh
pkg-config --define-prefix --static --libs libcurl
```

returns:

```
-LD:/Prog/winlibs64-11.1.0/custombuilt/lib -lcurl -lidn2 -lrtmp -lssh2 -lnettle
-lgnutls -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lgss -lwldap32 -lzstd -lz -lws2_32 -lrtmp
```

Note that with MinGW the order of the libraries is also important. The library providing a symbol should be mention on the linker command line after the object that refers to that symbol.

Finally you need to make sure that each library you include was in fact built and used statically. With that I mean no stuff like `__declspec(dllexport)` may be used when building it, and no `__declspec(dllimport)` may be used when compiling anything that depends on it. For some libraries this may require specific defines before including the library's header(s).

Specifically for libcurl and nghttp2 I find that it helps to add the following at the top of `lib/http2.c` and `lib/http.c` when building libcurl:

```c
#if defined(BUILDING_LIBCURL) && !defined(DLL_EXPORT)
#define NGHTTP2_STATICLIB
#endif
```

This will define `NGHTTP2_STATICLIB` when building static libcurl.

I have reported this as a bug at: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/7353

Comment: Sound perfect - will try MSYS2!

But, I fixed everything and am so very close to compiling my program using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-10.2.0.exe     -DCURL_STATICLIB     main.c    .\libcurl.a  ...  .\lib\libbrotlicommon-static.a .\lib\libbrotlidec-static.a .\lib\libbrotlienc-static.a     ....       -lws2_32 -lwldap32 -ladvapi32 ...`

But, I get: `undefined reference to BrotliTransformDictionaryWord`

Comment: @q-codes I built brotli 1.0.9 from source, but I also copied `lib/*-static.a` to `lib/*.a` and I have no such issues. Where did you get brotli from?

Comment: [Got Brotli from here](http://curl.se/windows/). And in the answer, `pkg-config` is from MSYS? And the `-LD:/Prog/.../lib -lcurl -lidn2 -lrtmp ...` is also referring to the libs installed by MSYS?

Comment: I myself use brotli built from source with no source modifications. You can get `pkg-config` from MSYS2, but you can set environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to tell it in which order to look for `.pc` files. Please be aware that static builds require all dependancies to be available, and their dependancies etc...